# Can't find fragment by tag for second time Android

Tags: android, transactions, tags, fragment

I have fragment with setRetainInstance(true) and trying to find my fragment after first launch.

```
    private void showHomeFragment() {
    mHomeFragment = (HomeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName());

    if (mHomeFragment == null) {
        mHomeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    }

    showFragment(mHomeFragment, false);
}

@Override
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {

    @SuppressLint("CommitTransaction") FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_container,
                    fragment,
                    fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());

    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    transaction.commit();

    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

I launch this HomeFragment than go to another fragment than comeback to HomeFragment and I can't find it by tag. Could someone help me to figure out what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can navigate back to `HomeFragment` by using `getSupportFragmentManager.popBackStack()`, which is the programmatic equivalent of pressing the back button.

Comment: @krislarson but the question was why I can't find it by tag if fragment has retain instance true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `addToBackStack` argument to `false` and not putting the replace operation on the back stack.  So it's likely that the `FragmentManager` releases the reference to the fragment since it doesn't have to undo that transaction thus there's no reason to hold onto the fragment anymore.  I'd have to try it out to be sure, but I'm pretty confident that that's what is going on.

Just to be clear, `setRetainInstance(true)` has nothing to do with this logic.  What that does is to prevent the fragment from being destroyed then recreated on configuration changes.  Once you replace the `HomeFragment` and it's not on the back stack, there's no point in having the `FragmentManager` keep that fragment around.